# Angular http.head on asset returns 404

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, httprequest

I created a service that checks whether a file exists or not.

```
fileExists(path: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.head(path)
        .mapTo(true)
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.of(false);
        });
}
```

I have a pdf file inside:   *`/assets/text/text.pdf`*

When I open the url in a browser, the pdf is displayed but when I run the path through the service, I get a **404**

```
HttpErrorResponse {
     headers: HttpHeaders,
     status: 404,
     statusText: "OK",
     url: "https://localhost:4200/assets/text/text.pdf",
     ok: false, 
}
```

EDIT: When I replace *head* by *get* I get a "Unexpected token % in %PDf..." which means it found the body of the PDF

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5170

If you have a solution for this...

Comment: do you encode this path?

Comment: No. I'm thinking it comes from the server not allowing head requests...

Comment: Did you try the HEAD request in Postman?

Comment: If you're using HttpClient (NOT http) you must add {observe:'response'} to get a full response see https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: @D.Simon postman says 404 as well. at Eliseo I don't get a response at all.

Comment: @gyc it is better to use relative path than complete url.

Comment: @KrishnaAnaril I don't use the full path. This is the error from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, webpack dev server doesn't allow HEAD requests by design.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5170

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/924

It's possible to make a proxy but it replaces HEAD with GET which makes non sense.
Another solution is to modify the middleware to make it accept HEAD as discribed in issue 924, which is overkill.